# 'CGPointMake' is unavailable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a Gradient class which I am trying to convert to Swift 3 but I get the following error

> 'CGPointMake' is unavailable in swift

for

```
func configureGradientView() {

    let color1 = topColor ?? self.tintColor as UIColor
    let color2 = bottomColor ?? UIColor.black as UIColor
    let colors: Array <AnyObject> = [ color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor ]
    let layer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer

    layer.colors = colors
    layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(startX, startY)
    layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(endX, endY)
}
```

Can anyone help me out with what I can use instead of `CGPointMake`

Here's the full class;

```
@IBDesignable public class XGradientView: UIView {

@IBInspectable public var topColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable public var bottomColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var startX: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var startY: CGFloat = 1.0 {
    didSet{
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var endX: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        configureGradientView()
    }
}
@IBInspectable var endY: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet{
        configureGradientView()
    }
}

public class func layeredClass() -> AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
}

public required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    configureGradientView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    configureGradientView()
}

public override func tintColorDidChange() {
    super.tintColorDidChange()
    configureGradientView()
}

func configureGradientView() {

    let color1 = topColor ?? self.tintColor as UIColor
    let color2 = bottomColor ?? UIColor.black as UIColor
    let colors: Array <AnyObject> = [ color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor ]
    let layer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer

    layer.colors = colors
    layer.startPoint = CGPointMake(startX, startY)
    layer.endPoint = CGPointMake(endX, endY)
}
}
```

Comment: First Google hit for `'CGPointMake' is unavailable in swift 3` ...

Comment: @MartinR you can use `CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)` instead.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In swift you can create a `CGPoint` in swifty way `CGPoint(x: xPos, y:yPos)`.
So change your `CGPointMake(startX, startY)` to `CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY)`

Answer (score 13):

swift 3 emphasizes in use of named Parameters.

`CGPoint` Can be created like this.

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 0,y :0) // CGFloat, Double, Int
```