# CGPoint is unavailable for Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, cgpoint

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336793/cgpointmake-is-unavailable-in-swift) could be a possibile duplicate. I've deleted and re asking the same question only to provide an answer that could help others to fix this issue

```js
collision.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "barriera" as NSCopying, from: CGPoint(0, self.view.frame.height/2), to: CGPoint(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height/2))
```

Comment: @TiagoMarinho I've asked and answered my own question only to share my knowledge and to help others who might have to face this same issue

Comment: I'm sure you asked and answered your question with the best intentions possible, but it's already answered somewhere else here. Deleting and re-asking the same question doesn't make it unique.

Comment: so what should I do? tap the "that solved my problem!" button as suggested at the beginning of the question? @TiagoMarinho

Comment: If the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946990/cgrectmake-cgpointmake-cgsizemake-cgrectzero-cgpointzero-is-unavailable-in) was helpful to you, vote it up. That's all you can do.

Answer (score -1):

```js
collision.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "barriera" as NSCopying, from: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height/2), to: CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: self.view.frame.height/2))
```

as a matter of fact all I was missing in the above question were x and y